# Why SQL Server insert's full range of spaces after data

Tags: sql-server

I created a table `[role]` with a column of datatype `nvarchar(10)`.

I then inserted `admin` (5 characters long), but it saves every value as `admin_____` every value gets full range value 10 long value returns (underscore space represents space).

Another column `[address]` is of type `nvarchar(100)`. After I insert select address:

```
MGL UB str GB-building 7 floor 702 number.__________________
```

so long space after data.  {100 long} defined max full length data

Comment: Sounds like somewhere the data is being processed as `(n)char` rather than `(n)varchar`. But we can't see your code.

Comment: normal insert column name value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it could be the case of [ANSI_PADDING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-padding-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

When ANSI_PADDING is `ON`:

> Pad original value (with trailing blanks for char columns and with trailing zeros for binary columns) to the length of the column.

Because you mentioned specifically `nvarchar` columns. The documentation linked mentions (Emphasis mine):

> The SET ANSI_PADDING setting does not affect the nchar, nvarchar, ntext, text, image, varbinary(max), varchar(max), and nvarchar(max) data types. **They always display the SET ANSI_PADDING ON behavior**. This means trailing spaces and zeros are not trimmed.

Your two options if you do not like this behavior are to change the column types to `varchar` and turn ANSI_PADDING off : `SET ANSI_PADDING OFF`. If you do this you will need to update all existing records to remove the padding with `ltrim()/rtrim()` as turning padding off will not affect existing records.

The other option is to remove the padding at the application level, when it pulls the data from the database, the application performs a `.trim()` or equivalent.